# Mac capture HD video via Firewirre

Tags: xcode, video-capture, quicktime

Kodak Playsport camera HDMI output to Canopus ADVC HD50. (works okay for iMovie)
Need source code for a simple program similar to Apples' "MyRecorder" tutorial that demonstrates video capture, and then a report of what resolution it is.
Currently my program reports: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -8961.)". Make sure that the formats of all video outputs are properly configured."

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me is to purchase Calibrated {Q}'s  XD Decode codec.